# Как завершить активити

Tags: android

Пытаюсь завершить активити и вызвать другую

```
  if (condition){
        finish();
        Intent intent= new Intent(StartAvtivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

но активити пытается выполнить и весь оставшийся код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `finish` класса `Activity` не является заменой ключевому слову `return`.

Вам надо явно в нужный момент завершить выполнение метода. В вашем случае - сразу после запуска следующей активити.